# AWK match exact string inside square brackets

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file similar to the below-illustrated data.

```
https://www.test.example.com [503]
https://www.tst.example.com [403]
https://www.tt.example.com [302]
```

I want to fetch lines that match with the second column. For example, lines matching [403] should print only `https://www.tst.example.com`.

I tried escaping the square brackets with the below command, which gave me a warning.

```sh
$ awk -F "$2 == '\[403]\'" file.txt
awk: warning: escape sequence `\[' treated as plain `['
awk: warning: escape sequence `\'' treated as plain `''
```

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit. Fundamentally changing the question after you have received several answers is not acceptable; it invalidates those answers and confuses new visitors, aside from unfairly moving to goalposts. Instead, (accept one of the answers here, or submit one of your own and accept that if you prefer, and) ask a new question with the requirements plainly stated up front. (Probably take care to explain how you represent any control characters, like a literal escape character.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing regular expressions and plain strings. `[` is a regex special character, but you are not using a regex here, just a literal string comparison. You don't need any escaping at all (though you might want to reverse the usage of single and double quotes for simplicity, unless you are actually using Windows).

```sh
awk '$2 == "[403]"' file.txt
```

In basically all the Unix shells, the double quotes you used don't protect dollar signs, so `$2` would be substituted by the shell, probably with nothing, or else with some unrelated string (whatever got passed in as the second command-line argument to the shell).

The `-F` option, if present, requires an argument; but based on your example data, the default field separator - any sequence of whitespace - should work fine. If you want to force it to e.g. a single space, try `-F ' '`.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -F'([[:space:]]*)?\\[|\\]([[:space:]]*)?' '$2=="403"{print $1}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Setting field separator as either spaces(optional)[ OR [spaces(optional) for all lines. Then checking if 2nd field is `403` then print the first field as per OP's request.

Comment: ITYM `-F'([[:space:]]*\\[)|(][[:space:]]*)'`

Comment: @EdMorton, merry x-mas sir thank you for always guiding GOD bless you cheers :)

Comment: Merry Christmas to you too and a Happy New Year (or Guid Hogmanay as we Scots say) when it comes!

Answer (score 2):

Will do what you want, with the benefit of allowing you to pass the desired code as an argument, rather than having it hardcoded into the awk script.

```sh
awk -v http_code=403 '$2 == "["http_code"]"' file.txt
```